# How to make a dictionary from list

Tags: python

let's say I have a list, how can I create a dictionary, where the object in the list is the keys, and ill choose one value as default. for example :

```
inp : [a,b,c]
out : {a:1,b:1,c:1}
```

all i can think of is this :

```
dict={}
list=['a','b','c']
for obj in list:
    dict[obj]=1
```

is there any cleaner way ? 
thank you.

Comment: try a list comprehension in python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `fromkeys` as ints are *immutable*:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(l, 1)
```

Demo:

```
In [6]: l = ['a','b','c']

In [7]: dict.fromkeys(l, 1)
Out[7]: {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}
```

Why *immutability* makes a difference can be seen by using a *mutable* object as a value i.e a list:

```
In [10]: d = dict.fromkeys(l, [])

In [11]: d["a"].append("foo")

In [12]: d
Out[12]: {'a': ['foo'], 'b': ['foo'], 'c': ['foo']}
```

A mutable value will be shared.

You could also use a *dict comprehension* which would be safe for either a *mutable* or immutable value:

```
d = {k: [] for k in l}
d = {k: 1 for k in l}
```

Comment: @limitless, no worries,  it's fine when you values are immutable as new objects are created for each key, just don't do the same when they are not unless you really want to share the object

Comment: How about a quick way to prefill with mutable objects, like initializing empty arrays in a way that wouldn't tie them together? Is the original for-loop the best way?

Comment: @mix3d, the dict comp is safe to use for both mutable and immutable values, each `v` in k : v  creates a new object presuming of course `v` is not referenced elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

```
>>> lst = ['a','b','c']
>>> dict(zip(lst,[1]*len(lst)))
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}
```